# How does "Чья бы корова мычала" have the meaning "You're a fine one to talk"?

Tags: идиомы

> **Чья бы корова мычала**...

Is this expression said sarcastically, with "чья" alluding to "твоя"?

> Whose cow would be mooing/complaining? Don't tell me it's yours (of all people/cows who should be mooing/complaining).

Comment: The full sentence is "чья бы корова мычала, а твоя (лучше бы) молчала".

Comment: The meaning is "you aren't the right person to judge ", so stop it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On occasion, the saying is often used in that incomplete form, but the speaker also refers to its second part:

> Чья бы корова мычала, а твоя бы молчала.

Literally, *it wouldn't be such a surprise to hear that moo in criticism from somebody else's cow, but yours should be silent*.

The sense: *it's strange to hear that criticism from a person, definitely doing what they criticize*. The sarcasm of the saying is a bit rude, but it is OK to use it within a circle of friends, closest co-workers or family members.

Comment: Hi. So is the interpretation "Whose cow would be mooing/complaining? {sarcastically}" good enough?

Comment: Yes, it's quite a possible interpretation.

Comment: Better don't use it even with your friends and/or family. Alex_ander underestimates its rudeness, I think. Not vulgar, but rude/condescending.

Answer (score 7):

Another English equivalent would be

> Look who's talking

A synonymous expression in Russian would be

> Кто б(ы) (уже) говорил? (но только не ты)<sup>*consistently ommitted*</sup>

Both expressions can be addressing some 3d person whose words have been retold, not necessarily the immediate interlocutor.